# Sorting arraylist by date in MM/DD/YYYY Format

Tags: java, sorting, date, collections

I have Date Field(String) with format (MM/DD/YYYY) comes from Service call.
My requirement is sort the list by date and display records by Latest date.

I have tried the below code.But I am not able to display records by latest date.

```
public class Test {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            List<Opportunity> oppList = new ArrayList<Opportunity>();
            Opportunity opp1 = new Opportunity();
            opp1.setName("opp1");
            opp1.setExpires("11/07/2016");
            Opportunity opp2 = new Opportunity();
            opp2.setName("opp2");
            opp2.setExpires("11/08/2016");
            oppList.add(opp1);
            oppList.add(opp2);
            List<Opportunity> opplist=sortOpportunitiesByDate(oppList);
            /*Collections.sort(oppList);*/
            for(int i=0; i<opplist.size(); i++){
                System.out.println("Opportunity Data>>>"+opplist.get(i).getExpires());

            }

        }
        private static List<Opportunity> sortOpportunitiesByDate(List<Opportunity> opportunities) {
              Collections.sort(opportunities, new Comparator<Opportunity>() {
              public int compare(Opportunity o1, Opportunity o2) {
                  DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/DD/YYYY",Locale.US);

                    Date date1 = null;
                    Date date2 = null;
                    try {
                        date1=format.parse(o1.getExpires());
                        date2=format.parse(o2.getExpires());

                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                  return date1.compareTo(date2);
              }
            });

         return opportunities;
        }


    }
```

Actual Output:

```
Opportunity Date>>>11/07/2016
Opportunity Date>>>11/08/2016
```

Expected Output:

```
Opportunity Date>>>11/08/2016
Opportunity Date>>>11/07/2016
```

Comment: a date is a date no matter how you formatted, you need to compare then in order to sort it..

Comment: try to call compareTo() using date2 and pass date1 in it

Comment: I have tried that way also .It is not working

Comment: Why don't you store `expire` as a `LocalDate` ? `opp.setExpires(LocalDate.of(2016, 7, 11));`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because format "YYYY" in your `DateFormat`
Change `MM/DD/YYYY` to `MM/DD/yyyy` will work

Answer (score 3):

you are sorting from the older to the newer date which is ok,
if you need upside down then do invert the comparation criteria by doing:

```
return date2.compareTo(date1);
```

another way to go is inverte the sorted list...

1st sort then do  `Collections.reverse();`

## Edit:

I try your code and the reason is  the format is not well defined, therefore the dates are wrong

try this:

```
 DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
 Date date1 = null;
 Date date2 = null;
 try {
      date1 = format.parse(o1);
      date2 = format.parse(o2);
 } catch (ParseException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
 }

                return date2.compareTo(date1);
```

Comment: return date2.compareTo(date1);This is also not working.I have tried it

Answer (score 1):

In java 8 you can write it in this way..

Please note that I have used apache CompareToBuilder.

```
Collections.sort(opportunities,
            Collections.reverseOrder((item1, item2) -> new CompareToBuilder()
                    .append(item1.getExpires(), item2.getExpires()).toComparison()));
```